# Wine32 Dependencies

Tags: wine

This is not a duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) which is for a very early version of Ubuntu and none of the suggestions fix this problem.

Wine has been working well and I have several Windows applications installed that work just fine but for some time now, whenever I click on any new .exe file that is not for something already installed, nothing happens. That is, the little spinner shows for a moment, then stops but no errors.

This is Ubuntu 19.10 and is fully up to date as of this writing.

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease         
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease [97.5 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease [97.5 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease [88.8 kB]
Fetched 284 kB in 1s (193 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

. . . and also checked Wine itself:

```
sudo apt-cache policy libwine
libwine:
  Installed: 4.0.2-1
  Candidate: 4.0.2-1
  Version table:
 *** 4.0.2-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

So I tried to run the application directly from Terminal to see if there were any errors and it gives:

```
wine Paragon.exe
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
wine: Bad EXE format for Z:\home\don\Downloads\Paragon.exe.
```

So then I tried installing wine32 as suggested:

```
sudo apt-get install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 4.0.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So then I tried:

```
sudo apt install libwine:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwine:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

which showed no sign of installing anything so then I tried:

```
sudo apt install libsystemd0:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libsystemd0:i386 is already the newest version (242-7ubuntu3.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
```

Trying to determine which build of wine is installed, I get:

```
wine --version
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
wine-4.0.2 (Ubuntu 4.0.2-1)
```

Whether or not Paragon.exe will run under wine is not the issue as wine isn't even trying to run it so any ideas? Incidentally, this happens with any other .EXE too, not simply this one.

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu?

Comment: @user535733 Ubuntu 19.10 with all updates

Comment: Please edit your question to show the complete output of `sudo apt update` and of `apt-cache policy libwine`

Comment: @user535733 Output added.

Comment: After adding the i386 architecture with dpkg does the installation of wine32 works ?

Comment: @JerareYoshi I thought I had posted that output in my original question (I'll review it when I'm back at the PC). It made no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Maybe you have a ppa that broke packages.

Comment: Have you tried to install wine (or any wine-related packages) some way that didn't work before this started to occur?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: @user535733 This is a secondary PC so nothing installed recently other than upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10 which broke MySQL but which has since been fixed.  Otherwise it's seldom used and no wine or wine applications have been installed.

Comment: @JerareYoshi No ppa installations either.

Comment: What is the basic `wine` package you installed to begin with? For example, I originally installed `wine-stable` which pulled in all the other requirements such as `libwine`.

Comment: It’s been some time that it was installed so I don’t recall which version but when I’m back where that PC is, I’ll check. Whichever version, I’m sure it was wine-stable as I never install other versions or betas.

Comment: i added output from wine --version to the question but it simply illustrated the problem. I also tried adding the individual dependencies but each one fails that it needs yet other dependencies.

Comment: @user535733 I just tried this on a second PC with identical results in that it asks me to run ***sudo apt-get install wine32*** but as with the other PC, the dependencies are not there so the installation fails.